# Answer section going out of bounds

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When editing an answer of mine, I noticed that the answer section goes out of the bounds that it's supposed to be in, as seen in the following image.

[image: answer going out of bounds example]

This can be fixed by adding

```
.answer * { /* Fixes the sizing */
    box-sizing:-webkit-border-box;
    box-sizing:-moz-border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.grippie {
    width: 660px; /* Fixes the grey bar on top of the preview */
}
```

Can we please get this fixed?

Comment: Stack Exchange is working on migrating all of our sites to a new global css framework that should fix this and other layout bugs. Graphic Design is on the list for an update soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed with the April 2015 [updates to the site](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/8708).

[image: screenshot of fix]